# ASP.net application fails after compilation

Tags: asp.net, compilation

When I take all the files in a website and deploy it on another server without compiling them it works OK. However, if I publish the website I get the following error:

`The file '/xxxxxx.aspx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested`

I'm totally confused and have no clue as to how to fix this. It seems as something goes wrong during the compilation.

The deployment server is Windows 2008R2. I do the compilation both on WinXPx32 and Win7x64 but get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error is misleading and 9 times out of 10 it is down to a missing assembly.
Have you checked the assemblies ?

check: http://forums.asp.net/t/956297.aspx

Comment: Yes I did check all the assemblies. I actually have a working one. But that one was developed buy some other guy and now I have to compile the project on my computer. When I publish it I get exactly the same files with the working one . But I get the above error.

Comment: What happens if you just FTP the website uncompiled to the server? Does that error ?